# Keras (Tensorflow) - name array_ops not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having an issue with Keras/Tensorflow deserializing a model. Basically this is an implementation of a convolutional neural network on text, which requires a dimension to be added at an early stage. The error message is this:

> File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/backend.py",
>   line 2231, in expand_dims NameError: name 'array_ops' is not defined

The code causing this error message:

```
import numpy as np
from docopt import docopt
import tensorflow as tf
from vdcnn import utils

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='1.0')

    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(arguments["--checkpoint"])
    print(type(model))
    proc = utils.Preprocessor(padding_size=256)
    data, labels, test_data, test_labels = proc.process_document(arguments["--data"])

    for i in range(len(test_data)):
        test_vec = test_data[i]
        prediction = model.predict(x=test_vec[np.newaxis])
        predlabel = utils.labels_in_order[np.argmax(prediction)]
        truthlabel = utils.labels_in_order[np.argmax(test_labels[i])]
        print("Truth: {} \t Predicted: {}".format(truthlabel, predlabel)
```

The code that calls "expand_dims" uses a Keras Lambda wrapper around the Tensorflow function:

```
...
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(self.sequence_max_length,), dtype='int32', name='inputs')
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(self.num_quantized_chars, self.embedding_size, input_length=self.sequence_max_length)(inputs)

embedding = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.expand_dims, arguments={'axis' : -1, 'name' : 'embedding_expanded'})(embedding)

conv0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=[1, self.embedding_size], padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(embedding)
conv0 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv0)
...
```

And, just for kicks, the line it's referencing in the tensorflow libs:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops

[two thousand lines of crap]

def expand_dims(x, axis=-1):
  """Adds a 1-sized dimension at index "axis".

  Arguments:
      x: A tensor or variable.
      axis: Position where to add a new axis.

  Returns:
      A tensor with expanded dimensions.
  """
  return array_ops.expand_dims(x, axis)
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 1.5, and this error occurs on both OSX 10.11.6 and RHEL 7. I've tried using various permutations of tf.keras, tf.keras.backend, just keras without tf, and all of it basically calls the exact same code, although sometimes it complains about "gen_array_ops" instead of "array_ops" with the same problem.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was this: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8123#issuecomment-354857044

On top of that, it required reinstalling everything on all machines and using `keras` directly instead of `tf.keras` to get the proper error message, apparently because of how Keras uses object serialization and the way Python "tracebacks" work.